# Cannot search correct result

Tags: magento2, search, search-criteria

I have a product named C.I.D

However, I am not able to search it in Magento 2.0

I guess it's related to the dot character.

Anyone got idea on how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to search for it via the admin view? If so, that might be a bit more complex to solve.  (I might recommend you search by SKU instead in the admin.)

Or, are you trying to search on the front end of the site?  If so, I'd recommend trying to set up a search term in the admin area of the site:

[image: Custom Search Term]

In this case, this would allow someone who searches on "C.I.D" to auto-magically redirect to the proper page, http://domain.com/cid.html

I did just test this, and it did redirect me over to the http://domain.com/ site (but it gave an error 404 message):

[image: Domain.com - error 404 page]

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am trying to search in front-end.

Your solutions seem not supporting partial keyword search? 
Actually I need to enter many combination to support a correct search (e.g. C.I , C.I. , I.D , etc)

Comment: Leo - Sure...  if you need to do partial searches, I'd add them each in as a term. That way you're covered.

Comment: But for those catalog without "dot" (e.g. tshirt, jeans, etc), I am able to get correct result with partial searches. Do you think maybe the SQL query cannot handle dot?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the MySQL fulltext search engine.
You may be more lucky by using a real search engine module.

If using Enterprise, give a try to ElasticSearch (or SolR but it is deprecated).
If using Community or Enterprise, you may have good result using ElasticSuite (also ElasticSearch based) : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Disclosure : I am the main developer of ElasticSuite.